# fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, console, react-native-cli

For some strange reason, apart from the general flakiness of all things RN and android I get this error when Reloading my app.

I run npx react-native run-android

Then I press d on metro and on the device I start debug which brings up a browser window (brave) and I press F12 to bring up the console etc.

Now and again when I "Reload app" I get the following error:

Failed to print error:  Requiring module "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\Platform.android.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules

I press Reload app again and I get back to normal

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it's showing when you turn on Android Debugging mode when you type "d" in metro.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).